# Should I write "so" or "so that" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, ellipsis

> He squeezed his eyes shut so (that) fear wouldn't sabotage his
>   determination again.

A native English speaker said I should remove "that."

I made a Google search: "so that fear wouldn't" vs "so fear wouldn't." The number of results are almost the same.

So maybe "that" here is optional? Should I include it or not?

Comment: can you give us the full sentence please? context is everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only apologise for having posted an earlier answer without thinking things through properly. I must also admit that I don't actually know if *"**that**"* is properly identified as a ["relativizer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativizer) here.

In OP's context, *"**that**"* is entirely optional, and my advice would be ***not*** to include it. BUT, it's worth looking at this syntactically / structurally similar example...

> *I paid in advance **so** we don't have to queue at the ticket office*
>     ...which has the two possible meanings...
>    1: ***so = in order that*** (I'm explaining ***why*** I paid in advance)
>    2: ***so = therefore*** (I'm pointing out the ***consequence*** of having paid in advance)

Including a pause (comma) before ***so*** steers us more towards the second interpretation, but it doesn't completely rule out the first interpretation. On the other hand, I'd say that using ***so that*** instead of plain ***so*** effectively *forces* the first interpretation.

In OP's context that second interpretation *(**so = therefore**)* is pragmatically unlikely, so we can reasonably say it makes no difference whether we include ***that*** or not. But there will be other contexts where you might include ***that*** specifically because you want to unambiguously force the first interpretation *(**so = in order**)*.